# A question related to the dimension of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and consider $S=R[x,x^{-1}]$.
I would like to show that $\mathrm{dim}(S)=\mathrm{dim}(R)+1$.

I know that for a Noetherian ring $A$, $\mathrm{dim}(A[t])=\mathrm{dim}(A)+1$, but I have trouble seeing how I can make use of this information to prove the above result.

Any hint/help will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest viewing $R[x,x^{-1}]$ as the localization $R[x]S^{-1}$ where $S=\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$.  Of course, you have the correspondence theorem that says the prime ideals of $AS^{-1}$ correspond to the prime ideals of $A$ that are disjoint from $S$.  There should be a way to argue there's still a chain of primes of the right length in the localization this way.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/798198/988132). The same question.